# How to work around the fact that `fun<-` starts by evaluating `value`?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, lazy-evaluation, assign

Consider the following function, it replaces the lhs by the value if the condition is `TRUE`

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) replace(e1, e1 == e2, value)
```

if `x == 3` replace x by 42 :

```
x <- 3
x == 3 <- 42
x
# [1] 42
```

So far so good, but what if `value` has side effects ? So far it is evaluated even if my condition is `FALSE`.

```
# desired: if x == 100, stop
x == 100 <- stop("equals 100!")
# Error: equals 100!
```

Is there a way around this ?

*See below some workarounds I found around this, but I would like to see if there's more.*

---

**EDIT :**

this addresses sotos' comment :

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) {
  cond <- e1 == e2
  if(any(cond)) 
    replace(e1, cond, value)
  else e1
}

x <- 3; x == 100 <- 'xyz'
x
# [1] 3
```

Comment: It also gives `side effects` If you replace with a string. Try `x <- 3; x == 100 <- 'xyz'`. It gives 3 as a string... `[1]"3"`

Comment: indeed, good catch, but this will be easier to address, the condition must be evaluated first and replace executed only if there is any `TRUE`. See edit.

Comment: Also this addresses my case as well: `==<- <- function(e1, e2, value) ifelse(e1 == e2, value, e1)`

Comment: is the `replace()` necessary? would not simply returning value when the condition is TRUE and otherwise e1?

Comment: @zacdav I want it to work with vectors in my real case (in the general case, for my example with `stop` we can assume it's length 1)

Comment: ``x=3;`==<-`(x, 4, stop("interesting"))``

Comment: yes in this case it is a regular function and the parser doesn't trigger the evaluation I guess

Comment: Where can I read about why evaluating `x == 3 <- 42` trys to call a function called `==<-` ? I can't remember seeing this behavior before.

Comment: I don't know how these functions are named, but you will get a grasp on this by understanding more about the functions `levels<-` then more complex ones like `[<-` and understanding that `==` itself is a function. I haven't found a good canonical explaination of these functions on SO, because I think they just lack a name. In general if you define `fun<-`, making sure the last parameter is named value,  then `fun(arg1, arg2) <- val` will behave as `arg1 <- fun(arg1, arg2, value = val)` ,

Comment: Then functions like `==` which get a special parsing treatment will also get a special treatment with their `fun<-` counterpart

Comment: @MichaelBird see Roland's comment under my answer, it links to a neat explaination

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to work around this :

1. `quote` and modify `==<-` so it always evaluates quoted calls
2. Use `~` as a quoting function
3. Use `~` as a shorthand for functions and use `rlang::as_function`
4. Use a function `delay` to quote input and add a class `delayed` so that only unquoted inputs and `delayed` quoted inputs will be evaluated.
5. Override `<-` to recognize `==<-` and always `delay` the lhs

The last way is the only one to work without changing the interface, though it works is by overriding `<-` which is generally not advisable.

### 1. `quote` and modify `==<-` so it always evaluates quoted calls

If we know we don't want to assign unevaluated calls
we can make sure our function evaluates everything, and just quote our
input.

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) {
  cond <- e1 == e2
  if(any(cond)) 
    replace(e1, e1 == e2, eval.parent(value))
  else e1
}

x <- 42
x == 100 <- quote(stop("equals 100!"))
x <- 100
x == 100 <- quote(stop("equals 100!"))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100!
```

### 2. Use `~` as a quoting function

If we know we don't want to assign formulas
 we can use a `~` instead of quoting.

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) {
  cond <- e1 == e2
  if(any(cond)) 
    replace(e1, e1 == e2,
            if(inherits(value, "formula")) 
              eval.parent(as.list(value)[[2]])
            else
              value)
  else e1
}


x <- 42
x == 100 <- ~stop("equals 100!")
x <- 100
x == 100 <- ~stop("equals 100!")
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100!
```

### 3. Use `~` as a shorthand for functions and use `rlang::as_function`

If we know we don't want to assign functions nor formulas we can go a step further and build a feature out of it.

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) {
  cond <- e1 == e2
  if(any(cond)) 
    replace(e1, e1 == e2,
            if(inherits(value, "formula") || is.function(value)) 
              rlang::as_function(value)(e1)
            else
              value)
  else e1
}

x <- 42
x == 100 <- ~stop("equals 100!")
x <- 100
x == 100 <- ~stop("equals 100!")
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100! 
x == 100 <- sqrt
x
# [1] 10
```

### 4. Use a function `delay` to quote input and add a class `delayed`

We can create a function `delay` which will `quote` the `value` expression and add a class `"delayed"` which our function will recognize to `trigger` the call at the right moment :

```
`==<-` <- function (e1, e2, value) {
  cond <- e1 == e2
  if(any(cond)) 
    replace(e1, e1 == e2, 
            if (inherits(x,"delayed")) eval.parent(x) else x)
  else e1
}

delay <- function(x) {
  x <- substitute(x)
  class(x) <- "delayed"
  x
}

x <- 42
x == 100 <- delay(stop("equals 100!"))
x <- 100
x == 100 <- delay(stop("equals 100!"))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100!
```

The good part is that it can work with any code that might trigger an error, the bad part is that `delay` is a strange function that makes sense only in a specific context.

We can mitigate the awkwardness by defining a proper printing method referring to the package help:

```
print.delayed <- function(x,...){
  message(
    "Delayed call, useful as a `value` argument of `mmassign` assignment functions.\n",
    "See ?mmassign::delay.")
  print(unclass(x),...)
  x
}

delay(stop("equals 100!"))
# delayed call, useful as a `value` argument of `mmassign` assignment functions.
# See ?mmassign::delay.
# stop("equals 100!")
```

We can with the same principles design a `STOP` function that will behave "delayed"

```
STOP <- function(...) `class<-`(substitute(stop(...)), "delayed")
x <- 42
x == 100 <- STOP("equals 100!")
x <- 100
x == 100 <- STOP("equals 100!")
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100! 

STOP("equals 100!")
# delayed call, useful as a `value` argument of `mmassign` assignment functions.
# See ?mmassign::delay.
# stop("equals 100!")
```

### 5. Override `<-` to recognize `==<-` and always `delay` the lhs

If we override `<-` we can make it work, but that's bad practice of course, so just for fun. If the first element of the LHS is `==`, then quote value and add class `"delayed"` and proceed as above.

```
`<-` <- function(e1,e2) {
  .Primitive("<-")(lhs, match.call()[[2]])
  if(length(lhs) > 1 && identical(lhs[[1]],quote(`==`))) {
    invisible(eval.parent(substitute(
      .Primitive("<-")(e1,e2),
      list(e1=substitute(e1), 
           e2= substitute(`class<-`(quote(e2),"delayed"))
      ))))
  } else {
    invisible(eval.parent(substitute(.Primitive("<-")(e1,e2))))
  }
}

x <- 4
x == 100 <-stop("equals 100!")
x <- 100
x == 100 <-stop("equals 100!")
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : equals 100!
```

Comment: [This mechanism](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) causes the evaluation. I don't see a solution to avoid it by just changing the assignment function.